# Magento 2 how to change order purchased from store?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-splitting

I recently installed an split order extension, however, this extension splits the order and sets Purchased from to the default store view. I wanted to know if there is a way to change the store here:

[image]

Comment: Yes you can change it from the database.